# Github actions/cache has no effect on my workflow

Tags: docker, caching, composer-php, github-actions

I am trying to run the following Github workflow for a php project:

```
name: CI

on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DB_NAME: ${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
      DB_USER: ${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }}

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up the CI environment
      run: |
        envsubst < src/.env.ci > src/.env
        docker pull composer
        alias composer="docker run --rm --interactive --tty --volume $(pwd):/app --volume ${COMPOSER_HOME:-$HOME/.composer}:/tmp --user $(id -u):$(id -g) composer"
        composer --version

    - name: Get Composer Cache Directory
      id: composer-cache
      run: |
        echo "::set-output name=dir::$(composer config cache-files-dir)"

    - uses: actions/cache@v1
      with:
        path: ${{ steps.composer-cache.outputs.dir }}
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-composer-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-composer-

    - name: Install composer dependencies
      if: steps.composer-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: composer install
```

The scenario is the following. I have a docker based development environment orchestrated with docker-compose. Php composer and other tools are run from docker images.

It seems that i am missing something here because the `cache-hit` is taking place as I see in logs:

```
2020-03-28T10:37:07.2837003Z Cache restored from key: Linux-composer-0dffe7e110c8249b30d4e46844fede7ea6b8e1433061bed12cbb9a2ae964e2bb
```

But is not taking effect because the step `Install composer dependencies` is still running and **downloading** artifacts. My expectation is that either does not run or run but does not download anything since it takes all from restored cached.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am missing?

**UPDATE**

I did accepted @edric answer because on this context where i asked my question his answer provided the solution for my question. Although I muss say it was not completely the solution.

I needed to delete the condition: `if: steps.composer-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'` from last step to get the rest of my workflow running. I did noticed that the composer cache was 
restored and that `composer install` was not run, causing problems later on due to missing dependencies. Without the if condition composer install run always but using the restored cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you didn't set an ID on the step that caches your lock file and you're also using the wrong ID in the following step to check if a cache was hit. I suggest that you should rename the ID of the step that retrieves the cache directory to a different ID so as to not confuse yourself:

```yaml
- name: Get Composer Cache Directory
  id: get-composer-cache-dir # Instead of composer-cache
  run: |
    echo "::set-output name=dir::$(composer config cache-files-dir)"
- name: Cache Composer
  uses: actions/cache@v1
  id: composer-cache
  with:
        path: ${{ steps.get-composer-cache-dir.outputs.dir }}
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-composer-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-composer-
- name: Install composer dependencies
  if: steps.composer-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  run: composer install
```